# Lock setLoading() to panel? Add msg to mask()?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to display a loading mask onto my panels.

Using `view.setLoading()` or `view.mask()` leads to problems:

- `setLoading()` is not locked to the panel/view. If you drag the window/panel, the loading mask with message stays in the drag start and does not move with its window/panel. The loading message works perfectly `setLoading( 'Waiting...' );`
- `mask()` locks to the panel/view (yea!), however it is not possible for me to add a loading message to it. Tried: `.mask( 'Waiting...' )` and `.mask( { msg: 'Waiting...' } )`.

I would use any of the methods, if it can be locked to the view and display a message. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
.getEl().mask("Waiting...");
```

On the panel that contains the view?

Comment: Do you know how to set the position of the msg box? Since it gets displayed at the top of the view border and not in the center like `setloading` does.

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to use .mask before the window has finished rendering.  It should always be centered.  If this is the scenario, the centering can be quite complicated.

Comment: Yes the view is still rendering. What to do then?

Comment: ask another SO question, since it takes some effort to explain, I may not have time and someone else can answer, or I would like the rep